# How can an algorithm for traveling salesman beat concorde?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, neural-networks

I am trying to learn about neural networks. I was reading the paper [An Efficient Graph Convolutional Network Technique
for the Travelling Salesman Problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.01227.pdf) which uses graph neural networks such that given a graph we get a hamiltonian cycle which hopefully is nearly optimal. However, they use as ground truth the [concorde algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorde_TSP_Solver), which when I ask google and chat-GPT seems seem to be an exact algorithm but in section *E (solution visualization)*, there are some cases where the author say :

> The model predicts a shorter tour than Concorde for this instance by
> choosing a different contour around the nodes at the top-left of the
> graph

But how can it be better? Doesn't concord compute the optimal solution already? Did I get something wrong about the traveling salesman problem?

Comment: Concorde is based on a MIP solver, and a MIP solver usually terminates when it satisfies some stopping criteria, for example when the optimality gap falls under 1e-4, or something else of this kind. For purely integer combinatorial problems with integer objectives (like counting something) that is probably "the" optimum, but for problems involving floating point numbers, like the length of a path, there could exist solutions which strictly speaking are a tiny bit better (within the tolerance). At least that's my guess; you would have to ask the authors for a definitive answer.

Comment: The paper is indeed poor on explanation. On $4$ places they say Concorde is used to get the optimal solution. Then on $3$ places they say their model gets a better solution than Concorde. And Concorde is reknown for solving TSP instances with tens of thousands nodes (admittedly with much CPU time). @MichalAdamaszek is probably right: the authors did not bother to adjust the stopping criteria so that Concorde would really output the optimal solution.